# What to do when cap falls from head in salat?

Tags: quran, salat, hadith

Sometimes, in salat, My Tupi (cap/hat) falls in the ground from the head when I go to Sijda or sometime in Ruku.

May be it is for my long hair. But I want to know, according to Quran and Hadis, what to do when I fall in the situation described above?

Comment: What I know is that the Qur'an and Hadith did not talk about wearing Tup while praying. It's not obligatory on you to wear it. Check this link https://islamqa.info/en/2436

Comment: It's better that you put your hat on the ground before you start. It's a distraction and there is no reason you would wear it while praying. If it happens that you're wearing it and it fell off, just leave it there until you finish.

Comment: @Atata None told that it is obligatory, rather it is Sunnat of Rasulullah (sm).

Answer (score 4):

aww,

Continue praying, without picking it up. Once the prayer is done, wear your hat. Any major action in prayer that might make someone think you are not in prayer would break it. Thus, avoid putting on your hat in prayer, and wear at the end.

The same applies if the imam's microphone falls off, or if your mobile or cards fall out from your pocket.

wwb

Comment: You explained it simple and factually nicely, and likewise correctly. Well done dear mate.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory to have head covered with something while praying. So, you can pray without a cap and prayer will be valid. Some scholars have said if it does not require much movement than you can take back the cap which is fallen. for detail have a look at [here](http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/did-our-prophet-pbuh-ever-pray-perform-salat-without-covering-his-head-or-wearing-cap-or-tu)
And on details on moving during prayer look [this link](https://islamqa.info/en/12683)
Besides it is better to push the hat back when you feel it is going to fall, or even more better to have a good cap which may not fall and disturb your prayer.
But, there are some people who THINK it is mandatory to cover head while praying, i disagree with it, and it has no proof whatsoever.

Comment: What did you mean about 'mandatory'? None said that it is mandatory(Farj or wajib), rather it is a Sunnat-E-Rasulullah (Sallallahu Alaihi wa sallam).

Comment: Thats exactly why you should not care, because putting a hat back if it drops in prayer is not sunnat. And i was pointing to the people who say so. I didn't knew if you have that opinion or not.

Comment: A sunnat is so silly matter, right? Because of some probability of falling it down, we have to restrict ourselves from sunnat! That means you are saying "Separating head from body by cutting is the only solution headache"!

Comment: I have updated my answer, with proper links. Jazakallah